# VBA: Color cells in a certain column, depending on value

Tags: vba, excel, search

Today, I had to deal with VBA the first time. After about 2 hours of research, I gave up and ended up asking this question, which is rather simple to undrstand:

On my excel Pivot, I search a column with a specific header "Percentage". After I found this column, I want to color the cells, depending on their value.
( >1 green, <0.9 red, <1 und >=0.9 yellow)

So far, I found the column (because it's not always the same column, I have to search for it). But after I want to access the value of the cell, I get a type missmatch error(13)

```
Sub test()
Dim x As Range
    Cells.Find(What:="Percentage", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    For Each x In ActiveCell.EntireColumn
        If x.Value > 1 Then
            x.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

As you can see, I iterate through the column. Is this already wrong?

I hope I could explain my problem properly and looking forward for some help

Comment: I don't think you need to use VBA for this, you can just use conditional formatting. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) for more infomation

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, looping through `ActiveCell.EntireColumn` doesn't return each individual cell, it just returns one `Range`, which is the entire column. Try looping by index instead:

```
Sub test()
    Dim columnNumber As Long
    columnNumber = Cells.Find(What:="Percentage", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, columnNumber).Value > 1 Then
            Cells(i, columnNumber).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through: 
`ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Cells`
On the other hand, looping trough entire column does not seem tobe a very good idea, you should try conditional formatting as Jordan mentioned, or try to retrieve range used by your table.

Comment: isn't this better suited as a comment? Also, looping through an `EntireColumn` is almost never a good idea. I would say never a good idea, except if the entire column actually has data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies.
I tried to do it with conditional formattig, but it is it even possible since the position of my column changes monthly?

@bobajob
I tried to run your code, but I got an typemissmatch(13) error here:

```js
If Cells(i, columnNumber).Value > 1 Then
```